# Why there is a train inside train in line 2 & 3?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am a beginner in python. This is an excerpt of a code from  https://github.com/minsuk-heo/kaggle-titanic/blob/master/titanic-solution.ipynb (line no. 12). I was trying to understand a bar chart with it:

```
def bar_chart(feature):
    survived = train[train['Survived']==1][feature].value_counts()
    dead = train[train['Survived']==0][feature].value_counts()
    df = pd.DataFrame([survived,dead])
    df.index = ['Survived','Dead']
    df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, figsize=(10,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pranjal try to learn a python module first (here, pandas) before jumping to any challenge (say, kaggle's titanic).

To answer your question, consider the lines you asked for -

```
Line 2: survived = train[train['Survived']==1][feature].value_counts()
Line 3: dead = train[train['Survived']==0][feature].value_counts()
```

The `train['Survived']==1` code results into a boolean (True/False) pandas series. It results into `True` where the column `Survived` value is equal to `1` else `False`. Once the series is generated it is fed to outer `train` and only the rows which are mapped to `True` will be kept and others will be dropped. Next you select only the `feature` column from the resulted dataframe and returns object containing counts of unique values. Similarly, proceed with line 3.

**Tip**: There happened no permanent change to the `train` dataframe.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. :)